# How to get last n number of records from a file using linux

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I'm running a command-line utility and it's producing 60 records(CSV) at a time and sleeps for one minute and producing 60 records again and so on.

I can redirect the output in a file but I want only the last 60 records to be saved (overwrite) for every minute.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: What is a record in this case? One line?

Comment: @Shawn CSV records (60 lines at a time)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using the `tail` command.

Although `tail -60` exists, I advise you to use `tail -n 60`.

Comment: Please find the actual command that produces records 
"kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test"

Can you please write me a full command to achieve this?